# XCode 4.5.2 why can I run apps built for iPhone on an iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store, xcode4.5

I've recently upgraded to xCode 4.5.2 and attempted to resubmit an app to the app store. The apple minion has run my app on an iPad and it does not work. So the app got rejected.

I tried it again and again, and the only way I can make it fail is if I run it on an iPad. My question is: **Why can I run the app that is intended for an iPhone on an iPad if I use xCode?**

- There's not storyboard file for iPad
- The targetted device family is iPhone
- There isn't even an icon file for iPad, so it just shows trimmed
  launch image on the iPad's home screen
- I cannot see the app that I published if I search for it on the app
  store if I use iPad

The bug that I'm running into involves treading and core data. Is my data model compiled for iPhone only, and not for iPad?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can run any app on iPad. Apps not targeted for iPad can run in "iPhone mode", which essentially is an iPhone simulator on the iPad.

Comment: An iPhone app that is not built for iPad most still work on iPad but in iPhone mode which is just "x2" in the bottom corner. This is done for you, you don't have to do anything for this.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "doesn't work". Does it not even launch? Does it run for a while and then crash? What "bug" are you running into that involves threading and core data? (Sorry, my attempt to mind-meld with you on that one failed...).